# Future after past

Tags: past-tense

If we start a sentence with for example "I saw" then use are obliged to carry on using the past tense it is wrong to say "I saw she is fat" we say "I saw she was fat". What if we start with present perfect "I have seen" and what's next ? Can I use the present tense " I have seen she's fat" or it's wrong too?

Comment: Couldn't you you find examples that were less sexist or body-shaming?

Answer (score 1):

When you start a sentence with "I saw," you're talking about the past, so you should **stick with the past** tense and say "I saw she was fat."

If you use **"I have seen"** (which is the present perfect tense), it's a bit different. This tense connects the past with the present. So, if something you saw in the past is still happening, you can use the present tense, like "I have seen she's very dedicated." But, if you're just talking about something you noticed before, and you're not saying it's still true, you'd stick with the past tense, like "I have seen she was very dedicated."

In your example, "I have seen she's fat," it can be **grammatically correct** if you mean her being overweight is still the case. But remember, how we talk about sensitive topics like someone's appearance can be important, so it's good to choose our words carefully!

Here are the rules you need to remember:

**1- Stick to the same tense**: If you start a sentence in the past tense like "I saw," continue using the past tense for the whole sentence. Example: "I saw she was fat."

**2- Using "I have seen"**: This is present perfect tense and connects past actions to the present.

If what you saw is still true or relevant, you can use the present tense after it. Example: "I have seen she is very dedicated."
If you're just talking about something from the past and it's not about whether it's still true now, use the past tense after it. Example: "I have seen she was very dedicated."

**3- Be mindful of sensitive topics**: When talking about things like someone's appearance, think about how to phrase it kindly and considerately.

Comment: Thank you James. Don't worry I don't jugde people by their looks these are just EXAMPLES. I didn't think much about them.

Comment: James, please stop begging for upvotes.